# emberjs binding with hash

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Guys could any one help me out.
Here is what I have,
[Ember binding with only an hash](http://jsfiddle.net/ashraf_zmn/DZynj/)

Here is the template,

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#each Page.PageController.content.tasks}}
{{#view Page.PageView contentBinding="this"}}

{{#unless editing}}
<div>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2> {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="editing"}}
</div>
{{/unless}}

{{#if editing}}
<div>
    <h2>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="title"}}</h2>
    {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="editing"}}
</div>
{{/if}}

{{/view}}
{{/each}}    
</script>​
```

And here is the js,

```
Page = Ember.Application.create();
Page.PageController = Ember.ObjectController.create({
    content: {
        tasks: [
            {
            title: 'Heading',
            editing: false},
        {
            title: 'Heading',
            editing: false}
        ]
    }
});

Page.PageView = Ember.View.extend({
    edit: function() {
        var content = this.getPath('content');
        content.set("editing", true);
    }
});​
```

The issue is that I can bind a boolean of a plain old hash with view Ember.Checkbox, but how can I do that with a link action?

Comment: I'm sorry, Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve/what's not working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Ember Objects` instead of plain hash for the bindings to work properly as in the above example you need to change your code as follows

```
Page.PageController = Ember.ObjectController.create({
content: Ember.Object.create({
    tasks: [
      Ember.Object.create({
        title: 'Heading',
        editing: false
       }),
      Ember.Object.create({
        title: 'Heading',
        editing: false
      })
    ]
  })
});
```

Let me know if this helps...

**Update**
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZynj/15/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that we can do with the ember object. In angular we can use plain hash. I was hoping if we can do that in ember as well. One other thing is that you see the check box binding is working, so I thought there might be a way to do so using link.

Comment: Can u please explain what did you mean by link ?

Comment: Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashraf_zmn/DZynj/11/). I would like to have an edit link and inline edit when that is clicked.

Comment: Firstly you can't use set on the hash, which is only supported by Ember Objects, see the fiddle that I've added to the answer again I had to use Ember Objects in order for the bindings to work, If you are getting the hash from the database model them into ember objects before using with bindings...